# Rename inside the crontab file

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting

I wanted to rename file name, putting in more details so that i can get my answer for my question:

I have the below lines in crontab

```
00 * * * * /home/@@@@/ulimit_nofile_status_20480.sh >> /export/####/$$$$$/ulimit_nofile_status.txt

00 * * * * /home/@@@@/ulimit_nproc_status_20480.sh >> /export/####/%%%%/ulimit_nproc_status.txt
```

I want to change the file names `ulimit_nofile_status_20480.sh` and `ulimit_nproc_status_20480.sh` to `ulimit_nofile_status_40960.sh` and `ulimit_nproc_status_40960.sh` respectively.

So in other words, I want to rename 20480 to 40960

I had tried below commands, but they did not work for me.

```
crontab -l | sed 's#/_20480\.#/40960.#' | crontab -
crontab -l | sed 's/\<_20480\>/40960/' | crontab -
"sed -i s//40960/" crontab -e
```

Comment: The `*` at the first part of `s` command is literal, try without it. (Excuse me for the downvote/upvote, my touchpad is behaving badly, the pointer was right above the vote arrows.)

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expressions are crazy.  The following should work.

```
crontab -l | sed 's#_20480\.#_40960.#' | crontab -
```

Your attempt required there to be a slash before the underscore, but of course, there isn't one in your `crontab` file, so the regex didn't match anything.

You say you want to replace `20480` with `40960` but several of your attempts look like you also want to remove the underscore before the number. If that is correct, obviously drop it from the replacement string.

I speculate your `sed` doesn't recognize `\<` which would otherwise have been a good attempt.

The last one of your tries is so far removed from any valid syntax that I don't think I can comment on it meaningfully. It parses as attempting to use the string `sed -i s//40960/` as the name of a command, with the arguments `crontab` and `-l` passed to it as parameters.